# Why when I try to create data it throws this error?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm getting a weird error when running the code below and trying to create register data for my application. Anyone might have a clue what's going on here?

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432       
    at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\bro\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\connection-manager.js:170:24
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\bro\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:213:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\bro\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:57:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:84:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

User.js

```js
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

sequelize.sync().then(function () {
  User.create({
       name: 'Steve',
       email: 'email@gmail.com',
       password: '123123',
       date: 02/1/2020
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this error comes when sequelize is not able to make a connection with your database. Can you check that your db is running at the specified host and port?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't start your database or wrong database config check db config: var sequelize = new Sequelize() or start Database